# Run Maven build/test with different dependencies and modules

Tags: java, maven, junit

While working on the current release of PowerMock we're faced with an issue. We're preparing to release support for Mockito 2 which is completely different from Mockito 1. Thus we've added a new module to PowerMock: **"powermock-api-mockito2"**.

The first issue is that **powermock-api** module contains two sub-modules:

- **powermock-api-mockito**
- **powermock-api-mockito2**

And only one module can be compiled at once, because each module depends on a specific version of mockito and cannot be compiled if both versions of mockito are added to class path.

**API module pom.xml**

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mockito</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>mockito</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mockito2</id>
            <modules>
                <module>mockito2</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

The second issue is that we have other modules (like junit and testng) depending on the API module at runtime (since the classes are loaded at runtime only one of the artefacts can be available in class path). So when tests are run only one module should be included as dependency.

For build/test time I've resolved it using profiles. I've created two profiles "mockito" and "mockito2" and the build is run twice.

**Root pom.xml**

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mockito</id>
            <properties>
                <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mockito2</id>
            <properties>
                <mockito.version>2.0.42-beta</mockito.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

**powermock-modules-test-mockito pom.xml** (but we have other modules which also depends in such way)

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mockito</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito-common</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mockito2</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito-common</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Dependency tree for profile "mockito" and for acceptance test

```
[INFO] org.powermock:powermock-modules-test-mockito:pom:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.powermock.tests:powermock-tests-utils:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:test
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.4.1:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Dependency tree for profile "mockito" and for acceptance test

```
[INFO] org.powermock:powermock-modules-test-mockito:pom:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.powermock.tests:powermock-tests-utils:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:test
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.4.1:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.0.42-beta:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:1.6.5-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

This worked fine until releasing powermock. The maven release plugin is used with a profile called **release** but the problem is that we want to release support for "mockito" and "mockito2" at the same time. But due to the profile conflicts we cannot apply both profiles at the sane time. The release process should only be performed once so I cannot run `release` for "mockito" and then another one for "mockito2".

I have idea for a workaround that looks like this:

1. Add "release" profile to API pom.xml and other modules which has the same structure (modules which submodules strictly depends on one of
   mockito version and mockito api)
2. Run install with "mockito" and skip test
3. Run test
4. Run install with "mockito2"and skip test
5. Run test
6. Run release:prepare ... but somehow skip compile phase at least for
   "powermock-api" module.

But again I expect big troubles on the step 6.

How I can resolve these issue? Is it possible to run same tests with different dependencies? Is step 6 is feasible ?

Comment: Use different dependencies in **different modules**. So one module which contains mockito and an other mockito2.

Comment: @khmarbaise it's impossible. One module could depend on one of the two version of Mockito, because for example a user can use jUnit either with Mockito 1 or Mockito 2. In runtime jUnit module is dependent on module which the user put in classpath. So test should be run with both modules.